# Загрузка файлов через AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, fileupload

Массив FILES не содержит никаких данных о файле.Что делаю не так?

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Surname">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="avatar">
    </div>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){    
    var form     = $('#form');
    var file     = $('input[type="file"]');
    var formData = new FormData(form[0]); 

    file.change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url : 'ajax.php',
                method : 'POST',
                data : formData,
                dataType : 'html',
                processData: false, 
                contentType: false,
                success : function(){

                }
            });
        });

    });

<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: попробуйте получать значение полей с помощью ф-и val()

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте

```
<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Остальное с виду всё верно. Если не поможет проверьте плагином [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/) , что запрос действительно содержит файл. Ещё возможно на сервере отключен приём файлов - проверьте `phpinfo()` .

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь FormData сам отправляет данные с кодировкой enctype="multipart/form-data">.Поэтому есть ли смысл ее прописывать форме?

Comment: @quaresma89 не уверен, что дело в `enctype` . Поэтому предложил ещё пару вариантов траблшота) Но лично enctype всегда прописываю. Но поидее с чего `FormData` должен прописывать `enctype` - ведь `FormData` это представление формы, как в форме написано - то и отправляется в ajax.

Comment: FormData использует такой же формат на выходе, как если бы мы отправляли обыкновенную форму с encoding установленным в "multipart/form-data".  Прочитал из документации)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form     = $('#form');
    var file     = $('input[type="file"]');

    file.change(function(){
        var formData = new FormData(form.get(0));
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            method : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            dataType : 'html',
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false,
            success : function(){
            }
        });
    });
});


Array
(
    [avatar] => Array
        (
            [name] => IMG_20160820_144534.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\XAMPP\tmp\php3FE6.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 682981
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, проверил у себя реквест уходит, PHP не могу проверить из-за отсутствия обработчика:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var form     = $('#form');
    var file     = $('input[type="file"]');

    var formData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append('file', file.val());

    file.change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            method : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            dataType : 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false,
            success : function(){

            }
        });
    });

});
```

В PHP проверьте так:

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    print($_FILES['file']);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Массив FILES пустой, только в POST есть данные.
Array
(
    [file] => C:\fakepath\IMG_20160820_144534.jpg
)